# Let $(X,P)$ be a probability measure space. If $f_n \to f$ and $A_n \to S$ with $P(S) = 1$, is it true that $\int_X f_n1_{A_n}\,dP\to \int_X f\,dP $?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, sequence-of-function

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability measure space. Suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $f_n$ is dominated by some $\mu$-integrable function. Let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of measurable sets converging to some measurable $S$ with $\mu(S) = 1$.

> **Question.** *Is it true that $\int_X f_n1_{A_n}\,d\mu \to \int_X f\,d\mu$ ?*

### A half-baked idea

Define $g_n := f_n1_{A_n}$. In case,

> **Conjecture.** *$1_{A_n} \to 1_S$ pointwise*,

which I suspect to be true, then $|g_n|$ is dominated by a $\mu$-integrable function and so the *Dominated Convergence Theorem* gaurantees that $\int_X g_n\,dP \to   \int_X f1_S\,dP = \int_X f\,dP$ since $P(S)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to show this is a  $2\epsilon$-argument. First note that for any integrable function $f$, we have that $$\int_X fd \mu=\int _S fd\mu+\int_{X\setminus S}fd\mu=\int _Sfd\mu.$$ As  $X\setminus S$ has measure zero.
Then we have that
\begin{align*}|\int _Xf_n1_{A_n}d\mu-\int _Xfd\mu|&=|\int _Xf_n1_{A_n}d\mu-\int _Xf1_{S}d\mu|\\
&=|\int _Xf_n1_{A_n}d\mu-\int _Xf1_{S_n}d\mu+\int_Xf_n1_{S}d\mu-\int_Xf_n1_{S}d\mu|\\
&\leq |\int _Xf_n1_{A_n}d\mu-\int_Xf_n1_{S}|+|\int _Xf1_{S}d\mu-\int_Xf_n1_{S}d\mu|\\
&\leq |\int _Xf_n(1_{A_n}-1_{S})d\mu|+|\int _X(f_n-f)1_{S}d\mu|\\
&\leq\mu(A_n-S)\cdot||f_n||_{\infty}+||1_S||_{\infty}||f_n-f||_{L^1}
\to0
\end{align*}
As $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $f$ is uniformely bounded, and $A_n\to S$.